# When including a date column in a multi-index, then calling asfreq, the other columns in the index are removed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some code that uses pandas `groupby` and `apply` along with `asfreq` to fill in date gaps for each grouping value.

```py
from datetime import datetime

import pandas as pd

# Original data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": [datetime(2023, 8, 31), datetime(2023, 9, 30), datetime(2023, 8, 31), datetime(2023, 9, 30), datetime(2023, 9, 30)],
    "name": ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c"],
    "constant": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    "value": [100, 101, 200, 201, 301],
})

print(df)

df = (
    df.set_index("date")
    .groupby([
        "constant",
        "name",
    ])["value"]
    .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq("d", method="ffill"))
    .reset_index()
)

print(df)
```

This prints out these two results, which works as expected. For each `date`, `name`, and `constant` value, new rows are added for each day until the next date, and the `value` amount is filled forward.

```
      date name  constant  value
2023-08-31    a         1    100
2023-09-30    a         1    101
2023-08-31    b         1    200
2023-09-30    b         1    201
2023-09-30    c         1    301

  constant name       date  value
         1    a 2023-08-31    100
         1    a 2023-09-01    100
         1    a 2023-09-02    100
         1    a 2023-09-03    100
         1    a 2023-09-04    100
       ...  ...        ...    ...
         1    b 2023-09-27    200
         1    b 2023-09-28    200
         1    b 2023-09-29    200
         1    b 2023-09-30    201
         1    c 2023-09-30    301
```

I'd now like to modify the code to include the original `date` value for each row. I thought this would be easy and I updated my code to look like this

```py
df["original_date"] = df["date"]

df = (
    df.set_index("date")
    .groupby([
        "original_date",
        "constant",
        "name",
    ])["value"]
    .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq("d", method="ffill"))
    .reset_index()
)

print(df)
```

But the result of this change is

```
      date  value
2023-08-31    100
2023-08-31    200
2023-09-30    101
2023-09-30    201
2023-09-30    301
```

Not only are the values not filled forward, but the `name` and `constant` columns are removed entirely.

Instead I expected this

```
constant name       date  value original_date
       1    a 2023-08-31    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-01    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-02    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-03    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-04    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-05    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-06    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-07    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-08    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-09    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-10    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-11    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-12    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-13    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-14    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-15    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-16    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-17    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-18    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-19    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-20    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-21    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-22    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-23    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-24    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-25    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-26    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-27    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-28    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-29    100    2023-08-31
       1    a 2023-09-30    101    2023-09-30
       1    b 2023-08-31    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-01    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-02    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-03    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-04    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-05    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-06    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-07    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-08    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-09    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-10    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-11    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-12    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-13    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-14    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-15    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-16    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-17    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-18    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-19    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-20    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-21    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-22    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-23    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-24    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-25    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-26    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-27    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-28    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-29    200    2023-08-31
       1    b 2023-09-30    201    2023-09-30
       1    c 2023-09-30    301    2023-09-30
```

I verified this has to do with the `apply(...` piece of the code. If I change that to `sum`, for example, things work as expected.

How can I include the original date in for each row in my resulting dataset, and why does including the `original_date` column remove the other columns in my example here?

Comment: pandas say : **Not prepending group keys to the result index of transform-like apply.** Your group has only 1 member by 1 group, so i think that pandas said "transform-like apply".

Comment: what version of pandas are you on? I am on pandas 2.1 and i get the expected output dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You put `original_date` as an attribute to `.groupby()`, so you get different groups (now based on the `original_date` too).

You can try instead:

```py
df["original_date"] = df["date"]

df = (
    df.set_index("date")
    .groupby(
        [
            "constant",
            "name",
        ]
    )[["value", "original_date"]]
    .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq("d", method="ffill"))
    .reset_index()
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    constant name       date  value original_date
0          1    a 2023-08-31    100    2023-08-31
1          1    a 2023-09-01    100    2023-08-31
2          1    a 2023-09-02    100    2023-08-31
3          1    a 2023-09-03    100    2023-08-31
4          1    a 2023-09-04    100    2023-08-31
5          1    a 2023-09-05    100    2023-08-31
6          1    a 2023-09-06    100    2023-08-31

...
```

Comment: Okay, that works and solves the resulting problem. But why does adding `original_date` to the `groupby` remove the other columns from the index?

Comment: Actually, this has the same problem when called with slightly different DataFrames. E.g., if I run this with just the first row of my example DataFrame (`df.head(1)`), a similar thing happens where the `name` and `constant` columns get dropped.

Do you know why this is happening and how to prevent pandas from doing that?

Comment: @KrisHarper You can try to update to latest `pandas`. When I run the code with `df.head(1)` I get the expected result.

Comment: Okay got it. This behavior was [added in 1.5](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#control-of-index-with-group-keys-in-dataframe-resample) it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use `resample`:

```py
(df
.groupby(['constant', 'name'])
.resample(on='date',rule='D')
.value
.first()
.ffill()
.reset_index()
)
    constant name       date  value
0          1    a 2023-08-31  100.0
1          1    a 2023-09-01  100.0
2          1    a 2023-09-02  100.0
3          1    a 2023-09-03  100.0
4          1    a 2023-09-04  100.0
5          1    a 2023-09-05  100.0
6          1    a 2023-09-06  100.0
7          1    a 2023-09-07  100.0
8          1    a 2023-09-08  100.0
9          1    a 2023-09-09  100.0
10         1    a 2023-09-10  100.0
11         1    a 2023-09-11  100.0
12         1    a 2023-09-12  100.0
13         1    a 2023-09-13  100.0
14         1    a 2023-09-14  100.0
15         1    a 2023-09-15  100.0
16         1    a 2023-09-16  100.0
17         1    a 2023-09-17  100.0
18         1    a 2023-09-18  100.0
19         1    a 2023-09-19  100.0
20         1    a 2023-09-20  100.0
21         1    a 2023-09-21  100.0
22         1    a 2023-09-22  100.0
23         1    a 2023-09-23  100.0
24         1    a 2023-09-24  100.0
25         1    a 2023-09-25  100.0
26         1    a 2023-09-26  100.0
27         1    a 2023-09-27  100.0
28         1    a 2023-09-28  100.0
29         1    a 2023-09-29  100.0
30         1    a 2023-09-30  101.0
31         1    b 2023-08-31  200.0
32         1    b 2023-09-01  200.0
33         1    b 2023-09-02  200.0
34         1    b 2023-09-03  200.0
35         1    b 2023-09-04  200.0
36         1    b 2023-09-05  200.0
37         1    b 2023-09-06  200.0
38         1    b 2023-09-07  200.0
39         1    b 2023-09-08  200.0
40         1    b 2023-09-09  200.0
41         1    b 2023-09-10  200.0
42         1    b 2023-09-11  200.0
43         1    b 2023-09-12  200.0
44         1    b 2023-09-13  200.0
45         1    b 2023-09-14  200.0
46         1    b 2023-09-15  200.0
47         1    b 2023-09-16  200.0
48         1    b 2023-09-17  200.0
49         1    b 2023-09-18  200.0
50         1    b 2023-09-19  200.0
51         1    b 2023-09-20  200.0
52         1    b 2023-09-21  200.0
53         1    b 2023-09-22  200.0
54         1    b 2023-09-23  200.0
55         1    b 2023-09-24  200.0
56         1    b 2023-09-25  200.0
57         1    b 2023-09-26  200.0
58         1    b 2023-09-27  200.0
59         1    b 2023-09-28  200.0
60         1    b 2023-09-29  200.0
61         1    b 2023-09-30  201.0
62         1    c 2023-09-30  301.0

[63 rows x 4 columns]
```

On pandas version 2.1, your code works as expected:

```py
( df.set_index("date")
    ...:     .groupby([
    ...:         "constant",
    ...:         "name",
    ...:     ])["value"]
    ...:     .apply(lambda x: x.asfreq("d", method="ffill")).reset_index()
    ...:     )
Out[16]: 
    constant name       date  value
0          1    a 2023-08-31    100
1          1    a 2023-09-01    100
2          1    a 2023-09-02    100
3          1    a 2023-09-03    100
4          1    a 2023-09-04    100
5          1    a 2023-09-05    100
6          1    a 2023-09-06    100
7          1    a 2023-09-07    100
8          1    a 2023-09-08    100
9          1    a 2023-09-09    100
10         1    a 2023-09-10    100
11         1    a 2023-09-11    100
12         1    a 2023-09-12    100
13         1    a 2023-09-13    100
14         1    a 2023-09-14    100
15         1    a 2023-09-15    100
16         1    a 2023-09-16    100
17         1    a 2023-09-17    100
18         1    a 2023-09-18    100
19         1    a 2023-09-19    100
20         1    a 2023-09-20    100
21         1    a 2023-09-21    100
22         1    a 2023-09-22    100
23         1    a 2023-09-23    100
24         1    a 2023-09-24    100
25         1    a 2023-09-25    100
26         1    a 2023-09-26    100
27         1    a 2023-09-27    100
28         1    a 2023-09-28    100
29         1    a 2023-09-29    100
30         1    a 2023-09-30    101
31         1    b 2023-08-31    200
32         1    b 2023-09-01    200
33         1    b 2023-09-02    200
34         1    b 2023-09-03    200
35         1    b 2023-09-04    200
36         1    b 2023-09-05    200
37         1    b 2023-09-06    200
38         1    b 2023-09-07    200
39         1    b 2023-09-08    200
40         1    b 2023-09-09    200
41         1    b 2023-09-10    200
42         1    b 2023-09-11    200
43         1    b 2023-09-12    200
44         1    b 2023-09-13    200
45         1    b 2023-09-14    200
46         1    b 2023-09-15    200
47         1    b 2023-09-16    200
48         1    b 2023-09-17    200
49         1    b 2023-09-18    200
50         1    b 2023-09-19    200
51         1    b 2023-09-20    200
52         1    b 2023-09-21    200
53         1    b 2023-09-22    200
54         1    b 2023-09-23    200
55         1    b 2023-09-24    200
56         1    b 2023-09-25    200
57         1    b 2023-09-26    200
58         1    b 2023-09-27    200
59         1    b 2023-09-28    200
60         1    b 2023-09-29    200
61         1    b 2023-09-30    201
62         1    c 2023-09-30    301
```

Comment: I like the idea of using `resample`, but this doesn't have `original_date` in the resulting DataFrame.

Comment: To be on the safe side then, kindly provide the complete expected output dataframe

Comment: Sure, update the question.

Comment: @KrisHarper note the way my result has the full dataframe, you need similar on your expected output dataframe; you can run this -> `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)` before running your code

Comment: Okay, I updated to include the full expected results. I am using pandas 1.4.

Comment: update to pandas 2.1 then... your code should work as is

Comment: Okay got it. This behavior was [added in 1.5](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#control-of-index-with-group-keys-in-dataframe-resample) it looks like.